# Scale single vector drawable xml for all dpi and for different devices?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Before the Addition of Vector Drawable in Android SDK, developer had to create multiple version of images for different display resolutions. With [`Vector Drawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) we need to create image only once as an xml file and we **can scale it for all dpi and for different devices**.

I had created a vector asset in studio

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,5c1.66,0 3,1.34 3,3s-1.34,3 -3,3 -3,-1.34 -3,-3 1.34,-3 3,-3zM12,19.2c-2.5,0 -4.71,-1.28 -6,-3.22 0.03,-1.99 4,-3.08 6,-3.08 1.99,0 5.97,1.09 6,3.08 -1.29,1.94 -3.5,3.22 -6,3.22z"/>
</vector>
```

It's placed in `drawable` folder and my hesitation is what I need to do to **scale it for all dpi and for different devices**  ?

Can any one help me to make these more clear ?

Comment: `"what I need to do to scale it "`, you dont need to do anything as it is scalable drawable which auto scales when its size changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to scale by yourself. That is exactly what Vector Drawable solves, by providing multi-density graphics.

If you're curious about how it works, check here: [this link](https://medium.com/@duhroach/how-vectordrawable-works-fed96e110e35#.yu9eisisj) and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) too